# Jenkins parameterization issue using Cucumber

Tags: jenkins, cucumber

I'm trying to find the right sintax for an instrucion that runs a docker image, maps a volume, and calls tests written in Cucumber with a JUnit output.

When I set the following instruction with "Execute command shell" in a job configuration and I don't map any volume, tests run:

```
docker run docker-registry.dev.xoom.com/agrimaldi/jasper:${VERSION} cucumber -t @co -f junit -o /opt/xbp_stamp_jasper/features/output
```

Problem is, I need a volume in order to read the output of the tests. So I try out with the following line:

```
docker run --rm -v /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/qacolombia/workspace/default/features/output:/opt/xbp_stamp_jasper/features/output docker-registry.dev.xoom.com/agrimaldi/jasper:${VERSION} cucumber -t @co -f junit -o /opt/xbp_stamp_jasper/features/output
```

But Jenkins doesn't seem to recognize the "@" symbol. I've tried with several positions of single quotes, for example: `'@co'` or `'cucumber -t @co -f junit -o /opt/xbp_stamp_jasper/features/output'`, using backslashes, double quotes... and Jenkins doesn't recognize the whole instruction. Would you please help me with a suggestion of a way of sending parameters?

Any help is highly appreciated.